# My decrypted password is 1 character to short

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cryptography

So I have this encryption / decryption code:

```
private string Crypt(string strData, string strPassword, bool bEncrypt)
{        
    byte[] u8_Salt = new byte[] { xxx };

    PasswordDeriveBytes i_Pass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(strPassword, u8_Salt);

    Rijndael i_Alg = Rijndael.Create();
    i_Alg.Key = i_Pass.GetBytes(32);
    i_Alg.IV = i_Pass.GetBytes(16);

    ICryptoTransform i_Trans = (bEncrypt) ? i_Alg.CreateEncryptor() : i_Alg.CreateDecryptor();

    MemoryStream i_Mem = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream i_Crypt = new CryptoStream(i_Mem, i_Trans, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    byte[] u8_Data;
    if (bEncrypt) u8_Data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strData);
    else u8_Data = Convert.FromBase64String(strData);

    try
    {
        i_Crypt.Write(u8_Data, 0, u8_Data.Length);
        i_Crypt.Close();
    }
    catch { return null; }

    if (bEncrypt) return Convert.ToBase64String(i_Mem.ToArray());
    else return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(i_Mem.ToArray());

}
```

I tried to improve it:

```
private string Crypt(string strData, string strPassword, bool bEncrypt)
{
    byte[] u8Salt = new byte[] { xxx };

    PasswordDeriveBytes iPass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(strPassword, u8Salt);

    Rijndael iAlg = Rijndael.Create();
    iAlg.Key = iPass.GetBytes(32);
    iAlg.IV = iPass.GetBytes(16);

    ICryptoTransform iTrans = (bEncrypt) ? iAlg.CreateEncryptor() : iAlg.CreateDecryptor();

    MemoryStream iMem = new MemoryStream();
    using (CryptoStream iCrypt = new CryptoStream(iMem, iTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        byte[] u8Data;
        try
        {
             if (bEncrypt)
                u8Data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strData);
             else
                u8Data = Convert.FromBase64String(strData);



             iCrypt.Write(u8Data, 0, u8Data.Length);
             if (bEncrypt)
                return Convert.ToBase64String(iMem.ToArray());
             else
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(iMem.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But what I am finding is that the returned decrypted password is 1 character too short. I can't see how this new code is wrong to the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `using` statement will make sure that the stream gets closed and therefore flushed automatically. Unfortunately you retrieve the ciphertext / plaintext from the `MemoryStream` **before** that.

---

Don't use `PasswordDeriveBytes`, especially not for more than 20 bytes, it's insecure. Rather use [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. So I move the if clause to after the main using statement. Right?

Comment: Also, if I use that alternative Rfc class you mention is it going to break existing encrypted passwords that were done using the current methodology?

Comment: I have moved the code and it is OK now thanks. I have not used the other class because I am concerned existing encryptions will not longer be valid.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle 1) yeah that should solve it 2) correct, but upgrade anyway, maybe use a protocol version before your encrypted data to indicate the new protocol 3) OK, great, see 2). Note that the static salt is not how it should be either, but for longer passwords with loads of "entropy" you should still be relatively OK - unless you want to migrate away from C#, cause then you're stuck (the algorithm of Microsoft is broken and it **repeats key bytes** when using two `getBytes` methods!!!). Another look at the protocol is definitely required.

Comment: Could you offer guidance on how to manage that upgrade you refer too? As for static salt, this is how the tutorials did it. I know no more than that.

Comment: Which tutorials would that be? Following tutorials like that is trying to get security by copy / paste. Not something I would recommend. As for the protocol, you could think of a header consisting of a magic number (large enough, say 64 bit minimum) and then a version; that way you can distinguish between one encrypted file and another. It's of course easier if you'd done that in the first place rather than bolting it on later (as now the magic should be distinguishable from random data), but this should work.

Comment: Well, I use the term tutorial loosely really. More like a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171625/my-decrypted-password-is-1-character-to-short/43173534?noredirect=1#comment73431542_43173534 But in my situation I am storing an encrypted password in a registry key. Then I read it from the key and decrypt it etc. So I don't have encrypted "files" as such.